# Вопрос по регулярке. Нужно исключить слово

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно вернуть строку за исключением слов в которых есть подстрока 'java'

Изучил регулярку, но вот никак не могу понять как сделать исключение , с [] все понятно, просто [^] и у нас исключается какой то из символов. Но, как исключить из скобочной группы?
`?!` и `?=` исключают, до и после текста, что очень запутанно. Мне нужно просто исключить слово  внезависимости от того где оно находится.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

```html
    const str = 'I like java to you  JavaScript is a comerese javascript';
    
    const result = str.match(/\w+(?!java(Script)?)?/gi);
    
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, лучше бы сразу привести ожидаемый ответ, во избежание недопонимания.
Думаю, такой вариант должен устроить:

```
const str = 'I like java to you  scriptjava JavaScript is a comerese javascript';
    
console.log(str.replace(/(\w)*java(\w)*/gi, ''));
```